# Reading [Object: null prototype] object throws `SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0` error

Tags: javascript, prisma

So I'm attempting to read the `count` attribute of an object, which is being returned as:

```
const PAGINATION_QUERY = gql`
  query PAGINATION_QUERY {
    itemsConnection {
      aggregate {
        count
      }
    }
  }
`;

const temp = readField('itemsConnection');

temp = [Object: null prototype] {
  __typename: 'ItemConnection',
  aggregate:
   [Object: null prototype] { __typename: 'AggregateItem', count: 3 } }
```

When I attempt to do:

```
const a = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(temp));
console.log(a);
```

I get the above mentioned error message, `SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0`.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Could you show how you got that object and the output of JSON.stringify()?

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(anything))` is almost never a reasonable thing to do. Not absolutely never, but almost never.

Comment: I tried replicating your issue using `Object.create(null)` and I get `"{\"__typename\":\"ItemConnection\",\"aggregate\":{\"__typename\":\"ItemConnection\",\"count\":3}}"`?

Comment: Also it seems like `object.count` would be the right answer, because that's how you access object property values.

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel I have updated my original post to show where the object is derived from.

Comment: That doesn't help in any way. Your object isn't even in a valid syntax and we still don't know what it really looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0` is a pretty good indicator that you tried `JSON.parse("undefined")`. Which means `temp` must be undefined.

Most likely, your `readField` function does not return a value or expects a callback instead. Make the function return a proper value and you won't get this error.